# Issue in changing view by dropdown of bootstrap datepicker

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-datepicker

I am facing problem with the bootstrap datepicker when I am trying to change the view of the datepicker as per mode selected in the dropdown.

Following is the HTML code :

```
Mode : <select id="mode">
    <option value="1">Day</option>
    <option value="2">Month</option>
    <option value="3">Year</option>
</select>
<br><br>
From : <input type="text" id="from" /> 
&nbsp;To : <input type="text" id="to" />
```

jQuery Code:

```
$("#from").datepicker({
            autoclose: true,
            startDate: '+1d',
            endDate: '+1y',
            clearBtn: true,
            todayHighlight: true,
});
$("#to").datepicker({
    autoclose: true,
    startDate: '+1d',
    endDate: '+1y',
    clearBtn: true,
    todayHighlight: true,
    orientation: "top right"
});

$("#mode").change(function(){
    jQuery("#to").removeAttr('disabled');
    $("#from").val('');
    $("#to").val('');
    $("#from").datepicker('update');
    $("#to").datepicker('update');
    $("#from").datepicker("remove");
    $("#to").datepicker("remove");
    if ($(this).val() == 2){
        $("#from").datepicker({
            autoclose: true,
            startDate: '0',
            endDate:'+1y',
            startView: 1,
            minViewMode: 1,
            clearBtn: true,
        });
        $("#to").datepicker({
            autoclose: true,
            startDate: '0',
            startView: 1,
            endDate:'+1y',
            minViewMode: 1,
            clearBtn: true,
            orientation: "top right"
        });
        $("#from").datepicker().on("clearDate", function(){
            $("#to").val('');
            $("#to").datepicker('update');
        });
        $("#to").datepicker().on("clearDate", function(){
            $("#from").val('');
            $("#from").datepicker('update');
        });

        $("#from").datepicker().on("changeDate", function(){
            var fromDate    = $("#from").datepicker("getDate");
            if (fromDate != "Invalid Date" && fromDate != '' ) {
                fromDate.setMonth(fromDate.getMonth() + 1, 1);
                $("#to").datepicker("setDate", fromDate);
                $("#to").datepicker("setStartDate", fromDate);
                $("#to").datepicker("update");
            }
        });
        $("#to").datepicker().on("changeDate", function(){
            var toDate  = $("#to").datepicker("getDate");
            if (toDate != "Invalid Date") {
                $("#from").datepicker("setEndDate", toDate);
                $("#from").datepicker("update");
            }
        });
    }else if($(this).val() == 3){
        jQuery("#to").attr('disabled', 'disabled');
        $("#from").datepicker({
            autoclose: true,
            startDate: '0',
            endDate:'+1y',
            startView: 0,
            minViewMode: 0,
            clearBtn: true,
        });

        //clear event for the datepicker
        $("#from").datepicker().on("clearDate", function(){
            $("#to").val('');
            $("#to").datepicker('update');
        });
        $("#to").datepicker().on("clearDate", function(){
            $("#from").val('');
            $("#from").datepicker('update');
        });

        //set startdate event for the datepicker
        $("#from").datepicker().on("changeDate", function(){
            var fromDate    = $("#from").datepicker("getDate");
            if (fromDate != "Invalid Date") {
                fromDate.setDate(fromDate.getDate() + 365);
                $("#to").datepicker("setDate", fromDate);
                $("#to").datepicker("setStartDate", fromDate);
            }
        });
        $("#to").datepicker().on("changeDate", function(){
            var toDate  = $("#to").datepicker("getDate");
            if (toDate != "Invalid Date") {
                $("#from").datepicker("setEndDate", toDate);
            }
        });
    }else{
        $("#from").datepicker({
            autoclose: true,
            startDate: '+1d',
            endDate: '+1y',
            clearBtn: true,
            todayHighlight: true,
        });
        $("#to").datepicker({
            autoclose: true,
            startDate: '+1d',
            endDate: '+1y',
            clearBtn: true,
            todayHighlight: true,
            orientation: "top right"
        });
    }
});
```

What I am trying to do is, I have three types of modes : Day, Month and Year. When I select the month in the dropdown, on its change event I need to remove the all the previous events bind with the datepicker and bind new events with the datepickers.

But, After changing the mode several time the events are not binded anymore and it stops setting value in the input boxes.

I am not sure if this is the proper way to do it, If there is any other way to do it then it will be very helpful.

Any help will be appriciated. Thanks in advance.

This is the jsfiddle link of the code : http://jsfiddle.net/tejashsoni111/aL9vB/2/

This is the link to the documentation : http://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.org/en/release/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just one way, create a prototype for your date/timepicker like this

```
<div id="fake_from_container" style="display:none">
<input type="text" class="fake_text" /> 
</div>
<div id="from_container>
</div>
```

Then whenever you want to init the date/timepicker, try

```
$('#from_container').html($('#fake_from_container').html());
$('.fake_text', $('#from_container')).attr('id', 'from');

$("#from").datepicker().....
```

The idea is: first, the fake_from_container is just to store the html code for input,
Eachtime you want to re-init the date/time picker, you will create the input from beginning, by copy the html code from $('#fake_from_container') to $('#from_container'), after that, #from_container will be

```
<div id="from_container>
    <input type="text" class="fake_text" /> 
</div>
```

Then, set the id for the input item inside #from_container

```
$('.fake_text', $('#from_container')).attr('id', 'from');
```

You will have

```
<div id="from_container>
    <input type="text" class="fake_text" id='from' /> 
</div>
```

Then, you can init the date/timepicker with whatever option for a fresh input #from

Comment: Thanks for answering but I am not understanding it completely, if you can change my jsfiddle code then it will be very helpful.

Comment: I modified the answer

Comment: Thanks for updated and more detailed answer, I implemented this solution it works with the dropdown change event but, still having some issues with the datepicker. For e.g : If I select any future date and then try to some other date past to the selected date then the date from the both input is blank.

Comment: As per your answer I updated my JSFIDDLE code : [http://jsfiddle.net/tejashsoni111/aL9vB/5/](http://jsfiddle.net/tejashsoni111/aL9vB/5/)

Comment: See the problem from your clearDate event, try to make the startDate and the endDate correct with your idea. I see the clearDate function called manytime and it clear all your values of #from and #to

Answer (score 2):

seems like you need `.input-daterange`.

### [full jsfiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/suhailvs/aL9vB/9/)

### html

```
<br>Mode :
<select id="mode">
    <option value="1">Day</option>
    <option value="2">Month</option>
    <option value="3">Year</option>
</select>
    <br /><br />
<div id="datepicker-container"> </div>
```

---

Now load `.input-daterange` into `#datepicker-container` dynamically (each time select box changes):

```
<div class="input-daterange" id="datepicker">from:
     <input type="text" name="start" />to:
     <input type="text" name="end" />
</div>
```

Then everytime the selectbox(`#mode`) changes, initiate the `.input-daterange` with `datepicker()` function based on selected option in selectbox(`#mode`).

### ie full javascript:

```
function initDatepicker(mode){
    $('#datepicker-container').html(''+
     '<div class="input-daterange" id="datepicker">from:'+
         '<input type="text" name="start" />to:'+
         '<input type="text" name="end" />'+
    '</div>');
    var $dtpicker=$('#datepicker-container > .input-daterange');
    $dtpicker.find(':input').val('');
    if (mode == 1) {//Day
        $dtpicker.datepicker({
            autoclose: true,
            startDate: '+1d',
            endDate: '+1y',
            clearBtn: true,
            todayHighlight: true,
        });
    } else if (mode == 2) {//Month
        $dtpicker.datepicker({
            autoclose: true,
            startDate: '0m',
            endDate: '+1y',
            clearBtn: true,
            startView: 1,
            minViewMode: 1
        });
    } else if (mode == 3) {// Year
        $dtpicker.datepicker({
            autoclose: true,
            startDate: "0y",
            endDate: "+1y",
            clearBtn: true,
            startView: 2,
            minViewMode: 2
        });
    } 
}

$("#mode").change(function () {    
    $('#datepicker-container > .input-daterange').datepicker('remove');
    initDatepicker($(this).val());
});
initDatepicker(1);// for first time initiate Day
```

Comment: Thanks for answering. I tried to implement your demo but as per my requirement there are some **extra conditions** with the date selections like: if I select a date in the **FROM** then the startDate of **TO** becomes the selected date and when I select date in **TO** then the endDate of the **FROM** becomes the date selected in the **TO** calendar. I tried to set some options and methods with this code but not able to get the desired output.

Answer (score 1):

Just use

```
$('#ID').datepicker('destroy');
```

Before Creating datepicker view,
It will destroy previous one and apply new datepicker ui as you want

Comment: I already used it, its not working with the bootstrap datepicker, In bootstarp datepicker there is no method like `destroy`, they have given `remove` and I am already using it.